# Is there a clean way to display a hyphen with haml

Tags: haml

I have this partial that renders a line containing three peaces of data contained in a span, and between the spans there is a hyphen. Since the hyphen is a haml keyword (or whatever you call that) you can't just put it between the spans, or haml would go looking for a function or variable. So I've got this

```
%p
  %span{ :class => 'client'}= "#{ won_or_lost['object']['deal']['client'] }"
  = "-"
  %span{ :class => 'value'}= "#{ won_or_lost['object']['deal']['value'] }"
  = "- Thanks to"
  %span{ :class => 'owner'}= "#{ won_or_lost['object']['deal']['owner'] }
```

You probably agree with me that

> = "-"

is rather ugly. It's not a real problem, but is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: It may seem minor but since this comes up in a search for "dash" it's actually important to specify that what you're referring to is a hyphen, not a dash. That is, the haml special character is a hyphen, what you get when you push that key on the keyboard is a hyphen, and what you've typed above is a hyphen. I'll leave the question as to whether it is really best to use a hyphen or a dash as an exercise for the reader ;)

Comment: Thanks @cesoid! I'm not a native English speaker, I was not aware of the difference between hyphens and dashes.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
%p
  %span.client= won_or_lost['object']['deal']['client']
  \-
  %span.value= won_or_lost['object']['deal']['value']
  \- Thanks to
  %span.owner= won_or_lost['object']['deal']['owner']
```

http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#escaping_

Answer (score 14):

I sometimes prefer to use an Em-dash, which I think looks better typographically:

```
%p
  %span.client= won_or_lost['object']['deal']['client']
  &mdash; 
  %span.value= won_or_lost['object']['deal']['value']
  &mdash; Thanks to
  %span.owner= won_or_lost['object']['deal']['owner']
```

Comment: In my opinion this is a superior solution, since it looks nicer on screen. When you are indicating ranges of time, the Chicago Manual of Style actually recommends you use em-dash instead of a hyphen.

Comment: Plus, it doesn't have to be escaped in HAML.

Comment: What looks nice or better seems completely out of scope to me, and is very questionable, even though personally I tend to agree. Still, my question was how to use the regular dash, so Heikki's answer is much more relevant.

Comment: Well, yours (-) wasn't a "regular dash" at all, that's a _hyphen_, and it's almost always the wrong thing to use other than for hyphenation. I think that was his point. Ranges and mathematical "minus" use en-dashes like this: "from  5–6 PM" or "2–1=1" and most other situations (other than hyphenating words), em-dashes are what is appropriate—such as in this sentence here.

Comment: For what it's worth, the an em dash should not be used for subtraction, but only a range between to things. A minus sign (e.g. − or &minus;) is appropriate.  Lastly, the em dash used in your last sentence is inappropriate, as it is not a break in thought.  Neither would a comma suffice, as it is not a complete sentence.